# How to parse HTML with jquery mobile

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-mobile, jsoup

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to parse the HTML to use in jquery mobile.  For example I want to parse the advisory section from this link (http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/metro_service_status/advisories.cfm?AID=4503) however I'm not sure what's the best way. I looked at JSOUP but i'm not sure if this will work for a jquery mobile app.  Then I saw this link (http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/m4QCt/) and thought it could be done with AJAX.  However it doesn't seem to be working.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    baseUrl = "http://www.mashable.com";
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "",
        success: function(data) {
            //code
        } 
     });
});
```

Comment: JSOUP is a java library, not JS? Generally you would use Ajax simply to pass data and/or receive a response to a server-side language that would do the html parsing -- ie java & jsoup like you mentioned, or php, etc on the back-end. You more likely want to be using JQuery Mobile to handle your front-end  logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin:

> http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

It helps with cross-origin ajax calls.

Then the script becomes something like this:

```
var baseUrl = "http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/metro_service_status/advisories.cfm?AID=4503";
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: baseUrl,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log($(data));
        var $advisory = $(data).find(".internal-box2-inner");
        $advisory.find("a").remove();
        $advisory.find("script").remove();
        $( '#theResults' ).html($advisory);
    }
});
```

`.internal-box2-inner` is the class of the DIV that has the actual advisory text.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/2y709fu7/1/)**

Comment: Woohooo!!! =D  Thank you so much!!!  It works perfectly!!!  I was looking at other sections on that page and I was wondering if it would be possible to use this on this form http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/tripplanner/tripplanner_form_solo.cfm   All I want is to be able to input the "to" and "from" and then display the different itineraries.

Comment: @speedracer2003, maybe you can just put the trip planner inside an iframe in your site?

Comment: Hi there, sorry to bother you.  I wanted to try and format the text color and size of the text however the content is not showing up.  I only see a blank page.  I checked your jfiddle example and it also doesn't show the content.  It was working fine last night but not now.  Any recommendations?  Thank you

Comment: @speedracer2003, the plugin uses google apps script which limits the number of calls. you need to implement your own proxy. see bottom of page: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html